# No cargar los archivos Javascript despues de cambio de componentes en angular

Tags: angular

tengo varios archivos javascript que su funcion lo que hace es cargar un slider. cuando cargo la pagina el slider sale perfectamente. el problema ocurre es cuando uso `routerLink="index"` al cambiar de componenete el slider deja de funcionar

```
<li class="menu_mm"><a routerLink="index">Inicio</a></li>
<li class="menu_mm"><a routerLink="ropa">Ropa</a></li>
```

pero si coloco de esta manera

```
<li class="menu_mm"><a href="index">Inicio</a></li>
 <li class="menu_mm"><a routerLink="ropa">Ropa</a></li>
```

el slider carga perfectamente por que la pagina se recarga toda. alguien conoce una forma de solucionar este problema para que funcione de esta manera

```
<li class="menu_mm"><a routerLink="index">Inicio</a></li>
<li class="menu_mm"><a routerLink="ropa">Ropa</a></li>
```

esto son los scripts que tengo cargado en el index del proyecto angular

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CaccaoBoutique</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="description" content="Wish shop project">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="assets/plugins/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/owl.theme.default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/animate.css">
<link href="assets/plugins/colorbox/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/styles/main_styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/styles/responsive.css">

</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/styles/bootstrap4/popper.js"></script>
<script src="assets/styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/easing/easing.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/parallax-js-master/parallax.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/owl.carousel.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

esto es lo que tengo en el iniciocomponent el slider

```
<!-- Home -->

<div class="home">

    <!-- Home Slider -->

    <div class="home_slider_container">
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme home_slider">

            <!-- Home Slider Item -->
            <div class="owl-item">
                <div class="home_slider_background" style="background-image:url(assets/home_slider_1.jpg)"></div>
                <div class="home_slider_content">
                    <div class="home_slider_content_inner">
                        <div class="home_slider_subtitle">Precios Promocionales</div>
                        <div class="home_slider_title">Nueva Coleccion</div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="owl-item">
                <div class="home_slider_background" style="background-image:url(assets/home_slider_1.jpg)"></div>
                <div class="home_slider_content">
                    <div class="home_slider_content_inner">
                        <div class="home_slider_subtitle">Promo Prices</div>
                        <div class="home_slider_title">New Collection</div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Home Slider Nav -->

        <div class="home_slider_next d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center"><img src="assets/arrow_r.png" alt=""></div>

        <!-- Home Slider Dots -->

        <div class="home_slider_dots_container">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="home_slider_dots">
                            <ul id="home_slider_custom_dots" class="home_slider_custom_dots">
                                <li class="home_slider_custom_dot active">01.<div></div></li>
                                <li class="home_slider_custom_dot">02.<div></div></li>
                                <li class="home_slider_custom_dot">03.<div></div></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

aqui de muestro como al regresar al componenete inicial donde muestro slider deja de funcionar

[image: aqui es cuando comienza]

[image: me dirijo a componenete ropa]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta esto `[routerLink]="['/carpeta/modulo']"`, El slider esta en el app-component ? o lo estas llamando en otro componente ?

Comment: coloca la barra en el routerLink antes de indicar a que path "viajar". routerLink="/index"

Comment: Lo que debe estar pasando es que cuando la página se carga por primera vez los scripts que hacen funcionar el slider se ejecutan y lo activan. Cuando navegas usando routerLink los scripts ya no se vuelven a ejecutar porque no se está recargando la página. De ser ese el caso la solución sería volver a llamar las funciones de los scripts que inicializan el slider cuando el componente se cargue.

Comment: crrlos como puedo hacer eso

Comment: el slider esta en un componente que se llama componente inicio que es el que se ve arriba si navego al regresar a ese componente ya el slider no carga

Comment: Qué librería usas para el slider? Puedo intentar hacerte un código de ejemplo.

Comment: arriba estan todos los css y js que uso en el proyecto. pero solo funciona cuando se carga la primera vez despues de navegar con routerlink deja de funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Te anexo el ejemplo.

En el index están las librerías de jquery y el slider.

Cuando el proyecto inicia puedes ver que no  hay ningún slider cargado, al hacer clic en customers u orders se carga el componente y se muestra el slider.

El truco está en llamar el método `$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();` en el `ngOnInit(){}` del componente donde está el slider así cuando el componente se carga se ejecuta el javascript del slider.

Antes de eso, después de la sección de imports del componente agrega esto: `declare var $;`. Eso servirá para acceder a Jquery.

Los componente se llaman `CustomerListComponent` y `OrderListComponent` ( usé la plantilla por defecto)

[ejemplo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mZFecm7K7Fa654J1An-kPprzV3JFiW8t)

Así debió quedar tu InicioComponent.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var $;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-inicio',
  templateUrl: './inicio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inicio.component.css']
})
export class InicioComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
  }

}
```

despues de agregar esto sale de esta manera desde la primera carga

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/styles/bootstrap4/popper.js"></script>
<script src="assets/styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/easing/easing.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/parallax-js-master/parallax.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/owl.carousel.js"></script>

Comment: como hago para meter todo eso el ngOnInit(){}

Comment: No, eso déjalo en el index.html . Todos esos scripts se cargarán una vez cuando se inicie la aplicación. En el ngOnInit solo va el $(selector).owlCarousel(); para inicializar el slider que se encuentra en ese componente

Comment: Te repito , tu problema con el slider es que cuando un componente se carga los scripts que inicializan el slider no se ejecutan, por eso se hace una ejecución manual en el ngOnInit

Comment: lo que pasa es que el slider y otros componentes dejan de funcionar. yo solo mencione el slider pero realmente son varios componenetes

Comment: por eso la necesidad de usar todos los js que estan ahi, ya coloque lo que me dijiste y el slider sale ya da imagen. pero pierde la funcionalidad

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AicuQtY7tubA12Jsz4qUW9TuqGvl?e=DX6oTy

Comment: Deje el proyecto para que lo puedas mirar a fondo

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta, agregué el código de como debió quedar tu InicioComponent. Lo hiciste así?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96074/discussion-between-crrlos-and-alberto-julio-arce-escolar).

Answer (score 0):

usen esto https://core.gocoyo.com/docs/external/compodoc/injectables/ScriptLoaderService.html

```
import {ScriptLoaderService} from '../../core/script-loader.service';
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this._script.load('#orders-chart', 'assets/js/dashboard.js?' + Date.now() );
}
```

Comment: Lee [answer]: edita tu respuesta y explica brevemente qué hace el código y el contenido del enlace que agregaste, ya que puede que no esté disponible más adelante. Además, dale formato a tu código, con el botón que indica `{}`.